# Presenting viewController (within Navigation hierarchy) via appDelegate openURL function

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

My initial view controller is a login page, which checks if the current user is logged in. If so, a segue is performed to the next view, which is to a tab bar controller, whose default selected tab is a table view (that has been embedded in a navigation controller).

Within this table view is a list of event objects. When a user selects an event object, the event details display in a new view, and the navigation bar appears above, allowing the user to return back to their list of events. This is all working properly.

However, the application has a URL scheme that allows it to be launched via a URL. Within my app Delegate, I am able to capture the URL scheme and query I need.

My problem is when I try to present the necessary view controller. I'm actually able to present the view controller (which is an event details view controller), but this view controller is not within the navigation hierarchy, which I need. Can't figure out how to do this (again the below code is within the openURL function of appDelegate, which is called via my custom URL Scheme):

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        //the viewController to present
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SingleEventAfterCreationViewController") as! SingleEventAfterCreationViewController

        let eventListNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventsListNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

//set a bunch of properties on my viewController

//below is where I'm unsure. The correct view controller is presented, but the navigation bar above, and tab bar below is lost. Subsequently, when I click on a "user" of the event, the program crashes, I'm guessing because there is no navigation hierarchy. 

self.window?.rootViewController = eventListNavController

                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The crash text:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showProfileSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

I have attached an image of my storyboard to help illustrate my problem, as well as an image of what happens now when opening the app via a URL, and what action from that view crashes it. I've also attached an image of what the presented view controller should look like.

storyboard full screen: https://s3.postimg.org/oywzb595f/storyboard_help.png

my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]

the problem:
[image: where i'm at now]

what it should look like:
[image: what it should look like]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

Initially I was setting my Initial View Controller in my Storyboard, which I removed. I'm now setting it programmatically within AppDelegate's didFinishLoadingWithOptions function.

Next, within my app delegate function, I did this:

```
let rootTabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventsListNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

rootTabBarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNavigationController

//the viewController to present
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SingleEventAfterCreationViewController") as! SingleEventAfterCreationViewController

//set variables in viewController

firstNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

I may run into problems when the user is not already logged into the app (due to the initial viewController which I'm setting via AppDelegate), but my basic problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you! I have my storyboard pretty much exactly as yours and this is exactly what I wanted to do too. Been wasting the past couple of hours on it until I came across your question. Thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: @Isuru great, happy it helped

Comment: Awesome...you just saved me.

Comment: @NileshKumar sweet 